# Set rotation senter point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

How do I make the center of `#aa` as the rotating center point?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3syhn67/1/)

```
function roMouse(e, mkv){
          var oSt = mkv.oSt();
          var cX = (oSt.left)+($('#aa').width() / 2);
          var cY = (oSt.top)+($('#aa'.height() / 2);
          var mX = e.pgX;
          var mY = e.pgY;

          var radi = Math.atan2(mX - cX, mY - cY);
          var dgre = (radi*(180/Math.PI));

              $(mkv).css({
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + dgre + 'deg)',
                '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + dgre + 'deg)',
                '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + dgre + 'deg)',
                '-msTransform': 'rotate(' + dgre + 'deg)',
                'transform': 'rotate(' + dgre + 'deg)'
              });
        }

        $('#cc').mousedown(function(e) {
            $(document).bind('mousemove.rotImg', function( e2 ) {
            roMouse(e2, $('#aa'));
            });
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
            $(document).unbind('mousemove.rotImg');
        });
```

Comment: set **transform-origin: center center**

Comment: **transform-origin: center center** is the **default** by the way for most HTML elements.

Comment: @jbutler483: thanks. I already tried that. But doesn't work.

Comment: @Paulie_D: thanks. you're correct. But in this particular example my rotation point is 0, 0 at all times. I'm not sure why - I'm finding a solution to center the rotation point.

Comment: Depends on what you are rotating...browsers disagree on the transform-origin for SVG for instance.